# How to make backdrop cover the popover

Tags: reactjs

the backdrop loading screen doesn't cover the popover.  the loading screen only cover the main page but not the popover. is there any way to do this? i have tried the following code but doesnt work

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Popover from '@mui/material/Popover';
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography';
import Button from '@mui/material/Button';
import { Backdrop, CircularProgress } from '@mui/material';

export default function BasicPopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState<HTMLButtonElement | null>(null);

  const handleClick = (event: React.MouseEvent<HTMLButtonElement>) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popover' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Backdrop
            sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.drawer + 1 }}
            open={open}
            // onClick={handleClose}
            >
            <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
          </Backdrop>
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
      
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider increasing the `z-index` of the `<Backdrop>` component to be higher than the `<Modal>` (`1300` or `theme.zIndex.modal`):

```js
const { Popover, Typography, Button, Backdrop, CircularProgress } = MaterialUI;

function BasicPopover() {
  const [anchorEl, setAnchorEl] = React.useState(null);

  const handleClick = (event) => {
    setAnchorEl(event.currentTarget);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setAnchorEl(null);
  };

  const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
  const id = open ? 'simple-popover' : undefined;

  return (
    <div>
      <Backdrop
            sx={{ color: '#fff', zIndex: (theme) => theme.zIndex.modal + 1 }}
            open={open}
            >
            <CircularProgress color="inherit" />
          </Backdrop>
      <Button aria-describedby={id} variant="contained" onClick={handleClick}>
        Open Popover
      </Button>
      <Popover
        id={id}
        open={open}
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        onClose={handleClose}
        anchorOrigin={{
          vertical: 'bottom',
          horizontal: 'left',
        }}
      >
        <Typography sx={{ p: 2 }}>The content of the Popover.</Typography>
      </Popover>
      
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('app')).render(<BasicPopover/>);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-8Q6Y9XnTbOE+JNvjBQwJ2H8S+UV4uA6hiRykhdtIyDYZ2TprdNmWOUaKdGzOhyr4dCyk287OejbPvwl7lrfqrQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js" integrity="sha512-MOCpqoRoisCTwJ8vQQiciZv0qcpROCidek3GTFS6KTk2+y7munJIlKCVkFCYY+p3ErYFXCjmFjnfTTRSC1OHWQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@mui/material@5.13.6/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```